# Displaying field of another table in a gridview Yii 2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have one table named hosts and the other one is hostgroup. On my hosts' table it has these fields: id, name and `hostgroup_id`. On my `hostgroup` table its  fields  are `id` and `name` too. I wanted to display on the `view/index.php` from host  table showing its `id`, `name` and from  hostgroup table `hostgroup.name` according to its `id`. 

`Also, do you have any idea how I can make it redirect to the`update`page of`hostgroup` of that certain id?

In my `main_directory/model/HostsSearch.php` I have this:

```
public function getHostgroup()
{
    return $this->hasOne(HostgroupsSearch::className(), ['id' => 'parent_host_id']);
}
```

While under my `main_dir/view/hosts/index.php` I have this:

```
  <?=
  GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            'id',
            'name',
            'parent_host_id.name',
            [
                'label' => 'Name',
                'value' => 'HostgroupsSearch.name',
            ],
            'ip_address',
            'object_name',
        ],
    ?>
```

Comment: add this `getHostgroup()` function to your model file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this function in your `main_directory/model/Hosts.php` model file

```
public function getHostgroup()
{
    return $this->hasOne(HostgroupsSearch::className(), ['id' => 'parent_host_id']);
}
```

**Grid View:**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        'name',
        'parent_host_id.name',
        [
            'label' => 'Name',
            'value' => 'hostgroup.name',
        ],
        'ip_address',
        'object_name',
    ],
?>
```